# How to add page URL to list of pages in WordPress admin panel?

Tags: wordpress, admin

Currently, by default, the following columns appear in the list of pages in the WordPress admin panel:

Title

Author

## Comments

Date

and because I have AIO SEO installed:

SEO Title

SEO Description

SEO Keywords

Is there a way to have WordPress also display the URL to the page (at least the part of the URL that is created when the page itself is created)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page url is actually already there by default, it's just hiding. When you hover over a page title, several links appear below the title -- `edit`, `quick edit`, `trash`, `view`. `View` is the hyperlink to the page, which you can click to view the page, or right click and copy the link address to use elsewhere.

Otherwise, if you are using a custom/child theme, you could add the following to your `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter('manage_page_posts_columns', 'my_custom_column', 10);
add_action('manage_page_posts_custom_column', 'add_my_custom_column', 10, 2);


function my_custom_column($defaults) {
  $defaults['url'] = 'URL';
  return $defaults;
}

function add_my_custom_column($column_name, $post_id) {
  if ($column_name == 'url') {
    echo get_permalink( $post_id );
  }
}
```

Note: This just creates a text url to your page.

Also note, you **do not want to edit your functions.php file directly** if you are using a theme you did not create, as it will be overwritten when you update. If you want to add this to an existing theme, I'd suggest looking into child themes.

Answer (score 0):

This is helpful.  I would only improve the output slightly by removing the site url and just showing the page.  Takes up less space and less to weed through visually.

```
     if ($column_name == 'url') {
      $siteURL=get_site_url($post_id);
      $link= get_permalink( $post_id );
      echo str_replace($siteURL,"",$link);
   }
```